# How can I get the original request URL in the response callback?

Tags: node.js, http, https

I have a loop like this:

```
var req;

for (var i=0; i<sites.length; i++) {
    req = https.get(sites[i], handleRequest);
    req.on('error', handleError);
}
```

The callback (`handleRequest`) runs asynchronously, for each website being requested.

However, the only parameter in handleRequest seems to be a "response".
When the callback is run, the loop has already completed, so how can I keep track of which website is this response for, so I can handle it accordingly?

Comment: Does the response not say where it came from? I'm looking at [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) but it doesn't explain the response object. From the code samples, I can see that it has a `headers` property, so I'd expect it has the origin URL there.

Comment: Nope. Headers just show something like this: {
    "date": "Thu, 10 Oct 2019 16:30:08 GMT",
    "server": "Apache",
    "connection": "close",
    "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
    "content-type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
}

Comment: OK...weird. Anyway, I think I have a solution for you, then.

Comment: Bring it on!! :) thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your `handleRequest` to take two parameters - `url` being the first of them. With that you can [partially apply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) the function via [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions) and so *set* the `url` parameter at the time of calling but you'll still wait for the second argument.

```js
let sites = [
  "https://example.com",
  "https://example.net",
  "https://example.org"
];

function handleRequest(url, res) {
  console.log("handling:", url);
  
  /* handling code */
}

//minimalistic dummy HTTP module that responds after 1 second
let https = {
  get: handler => setTimeout(handler, 1000)
}

for (var i=0; i < sites.length; i++) {
    let url = sites[i];
    https.get(handleRequest.bind(this, url)) //partially apply handleRequest
}
```

You can get a similar result via [currying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying) - instead of having two parameters, first take one, then return a function that takes the other. It leads to (in my opinion) better syntax when calling:

```js
let sites = [
  "https://example.com",
  "https://example.net",
  "https://example.org"
];

function handleRequest(url) {
  return function actualHandler(res) {
    console.log("handling:", url);
  
    /* handling code */
  }
}

//minimalistic dummy HTTP module that responds after 1 second
let https = {
  get: handler => setTimeout(handler, 1000)
}

for (var i=0; i < sites.length; i++) {
    let url = sites[i];
    https.get(handleRequest(url))
}
```